# Setting input values with the values returning from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and I want to set the values of the input fields on change of a form select. On change of the select ajax jquery runs and calls a PHP file with get method. But I don't know how to return the values from PHP (array or echo or any other way) and how to set them to the input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this could be desired solution:

```
<form name="frm">
  <input type="text" name="age" id="txtAge" />
  <input type="text" name="country" id="txtCountry" />
  <select name="name" id="selName">
    <option value="Ceyhun Ganioglu">Ceyhun Ganioglu</option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="CED">CED</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $('select#selName').change(function(){
     var name = $(this).val(); // selected option's value
     $.getJSON("<URL_TO_PHP_SCRIPT>", { name: name }, function(data){
             // on success, put returned value in textbox
             // return data is in JSON (note, I am using `.getJSON` now)
             $("#txtAge").val(data.age);
             $("#txtCountry").val(data.country);
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

Your PHP Code could be:

```
<?php 
 echo json_encode(array('age' => 21, 'country' => 'US')); // you need to return on the basis of name, :)
?>
```

Read Ajax doc for jQuery `$.getJSON` here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Other Ajax functions in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I found similar examples on the internet but as this one it is for a single value. I want to return an array or more than one variable.